# Is there an equivalent to the SPWeb.Properties in the SharePoint web services?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

Our project has a site template that manages custom properties using SPWeb.Properties. However I need to be able to change these values through the webservices and I am having trouble finding any methods to even return the custom properties.

Where can I find the equivalent to the SPWeb.Properties collection in the SharePoint web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a builtin service doing that. If you have access to the server, it should be trivial to create a service exposing this, though.

Comment: Shame really. Our release to production procedures take about 20 billion times longer than actually coding anything :)

Comment: If you deploy your template as a SharePoint solution, you should consider including a custom web service as a part of that.